# AngularJS Error: [$templateRequest:tpload]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaE67.png)

I don't understand what should I do...
What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

as i see it's a CORS problem, it means than your template is n the different domain.
try to use some http server for your app, not just html file